# Is Scheduling Posts Permitted By Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im toying around with integrating facbook into a website. Basically this website will generate acheivements for each user after X amount time (starting from a day up to a year).

I want to post these milestones to facebook automatically (with users prior permission). Does facebook allow this?

[This](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/192321904229684) article seems pretty darn explicit that its not.

But i have seen lots of posts on SO that are scheduling posts while trying to figure this out. Perhaps i have terminology's mixed up or something. Could someone explain this for me please.

If its not possible, does this mean that the only time an app can post to a users facebook wall is when the user explicitly clicks something to the effect of "post to my wall". Meaning they would need to login and manually approve every milestone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to post something on behalf of a user automatically. According to the [facebook's policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), *even if a user grants you a publishing permission, actions you take on the user's behalf must be expected by the user*, i.e. user must be aware of the actions you are taking on his behalf. As the article says, this can be done, for example, by prompting user with a dialog box with a link to Share a photo to their timeline each time your app would like to share to the user’s Stream.

Facebook however permits scheduled Page posts, but I guess this is not what you want. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/).